# Trouble requiring image module in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

Just getting started with [React-Native](http://facebook.github.io/react-native) and I'm having some trouble requiring a static image.

Here's the very-basic code I have so far:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
} = React;

var buzz = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('image!bg')}  style={styles.bg}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Welcome to Buzz! iOS interface to
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.welcomeHeader}>Charityware</Text>
        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  welcomeHeader: {
    fontWeight: '600',
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 50,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  bg: {
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    alignSelf: 'auto',

  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('buzz', () => buzz);
```

The main trouble area is:

```
    <Image source={require('image!bg')}  style={styles.bg}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Welcome to Buzz! iOS interface to
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.welcomeHeader}>Charityware</Text>
    </Image>
```

When packaging my app and running it, I get a render error:
[image: error image]

I understand that you need to add images in xcode as an image set in order for the `require` call to find the image and have added an image set to that end:
[image: bg image]

...But to no avail. Anyone have any thoughts? I've read the docs and *seem* to be doing this in the prescribed way. Thanks!

Comment: In our project, we use require('../../img/some.png') in Image so that cross platform team like Android & iOS guy can use the same resources in code.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since React Native release `0.14` the handling of images has been normalized for iOS and Android and is now different. I could not find any documentation except for this very clear commit note on Github: [Document new asset system](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/3545).

There's only a screenshot of the proposed documentation:
[image]

Update:
There is a link now for the real documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Comment: yep, that fixed it for me with React Native 0.14 . Good one!

Comment: This answer is up-to-date, compared with others.

Comment: Images are showing in development but not in production? any reason i am using react-native 0.27.2

Comment: Is there no way to use a variable to get a local image?

Comment: 2019 and still no way to use a variable to get a local image

Answer (score 31):

I had similar problem, then renamed the image files in file system under the **xcode** project's `Images.xcassets` directories with suffixes and capitalization to match the image I'm loading.

For example, if 
`source={require('image!Villagers')}` it required the image files named precisely as `Villagers.png`, `Villagers@2x.png` and `Villagers@3x.png`. If the '@3x' part of filename wasn't there, the image would not get found.

Comment: This worked for me. Also, don't forget to give the image a width and height or it won't show.

Answer (score 4):

What version of React Native are you running? There was an issue with the packager, related to that, that have been solved.

If that's the case, you can either update or run the dev server with:

```
node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --assetRoots path/to/Images.xcassets
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/282

Comment: It seems like the fix in pull #286 was later reverted by commit 31c4ff0. But bringing that fix manually to packager.js didn't seem to resolve the issue either (version 0.3.0).

Comment: Using `0.3.1`; @Pedro is correct about the reversion.

Comment: Confirmed it works on `0.3.1`. I had another issue here.

Comment: This worked for me on `0.4.1`. I added `--assetRoots path/to/Images.xcassets` to my usual `npm run start` command and `require(image!foo)` now works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

This question has already been answered, but if you use React Native on Android, you might have that same problem. For me, solution was using `source={{ uri: "google", isStatic: true }}` instead of `source={required('./bg.png')}`.

Just don't forget to add your images in `src/main/res/drawable` folder.

Comment: I am using react-native 0.27.2 and we don't further require to put images into drawable folder. i have problem only with production apk. is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: App build required for new resources
>   Any time you add a new resource to Images.xcassets you will need to re->build your app through XCode before you can use it - a reload from within >the simulator is not enough.
>   (from React Native docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#content)

Also make sure to restart the packager. That solved the issue for me.

Comment: Restarting the packager worked for me when I replaced an image with a larger version but kept the same file name.

Answer (score 1):

You can easy to refer the images by making the package.json file in your assets folder.

[Project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA4hv.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZp9q.png)

And you can call it by this code.

```
<Image 
   source={require('assets/img/avatar.png')} 
   style={styles.itemAvatar}
   resizeMode={'cover'}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For static images, you need to provide the path like:

```
<Image source={require('./images/back.png')}  
style= {{width:25, height:25, marginLeft:12, padding:12}}/>
```

This worked for me, for the image stored in images folder of project directory:

Comment: Path like what?

Comment: Due to some reason, it was previously not showing. I have edited my answer. Path like this:

<Image source={require('./images/back.png')}  
style= {{width:25, height:25, marginLeft:12, padding:12}}/>