# React Native Android - Static Resources not Showing

Tags: android, react-native

I'm just trying to load an image as a static resource. Here is an example that gives me a blank white screen.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */

'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View
} = React;

var impowerz = React.createClass({
  displayName : "Login",
  render: function() {
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={require('image!bg-splash')} style={styles.bg} />
     </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bg : {
    height: 667,
    width: 375
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('impowerz', () => impowerz);
```

I checked in Chrome Debugger and this is what I got

[![Chrome Debugger sees my static resource][1]][1]

**Edit** I wrapped the image tag in a view and added a flex: 1 styles for the container

**Update** I tried to console.log() the assetsRoot property in react-native/packager/packager.js and it came back as /impowerz/assets/ which is where my image lives. I made a @2x and @3x as suggested [in this answer][2]

I tried using .jpg instead of .png images and tried replacing require('image!bg_splash') with {uri: 'assets/image/bg_splash.jpg'} (with and without the ext).

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 5):

How did you add "bg-splash" to your android app? It should go under `android/app/src/main/res/drawable` (or `drawable-hdpi`, `-xhdp` etc if you have different version per DPI). Also take into account that android only accept resources names that contain lowercase letters and underscores, so your image name doesn't match that requirement as it contains dash sign.

Comment: I console.log() the `assetsRoot` property in `react-native/packager/packager.js` and it came back as `/impowerz/assets/`. I found the directory you mentioned and I don't think that's the correct one. There's already a file in there, so tried `require('image!ic_launcher')` and I received an `unknown module` error. Also, I already tried changing my image name to an underscore and that didn't help either. I used this as a reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308937/trouble-requiring-image-module-in-react-native. Can you show me where you found your answer?

Comment: kzzzf is correct. You need to place your images in the `drawable-hdpi` `-xhdp`, etc folders. Don't worry what the packager told you the `assetsRoot` is. I have a project where static images work just fine. Here it is in the docs: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#adding-static-resources-to-your-android-app

Answer (score 4):

in react-native v.0.14+

```
 // same syntax for IOS and Android
 require('./my-icon.png')
```

Full Image docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html)

> As of 0.14 release, React Native provides a unified way of managing images in your iOS and Android apps. To add a static image to your app, place it somewhere in your source code tree and reference it like this:

```
 <Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />

//relative path
.
├── button.js
└── img
   ├── check@2x.png
   └── check@3x.png
```

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, it seems like Vector Drawables are not supported. That issue along with the varying ways to include images really threw me for a loop.

Comment: that's new in 0.14+ . this way its easier , for cross platform andorid\ios solution

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get my images to show up either.
When I went to `<yourapp>/android/app/src/main/res`, there were only `mipmap-<qualifier>` folders.  I first put the images in those folders.  Didn't work.  My reading comprehension skills obviously need upgrading, because in the [instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#adding-static-resources-to-your-android-app), it clearly says "drawable."  Then, I made the mistake of thinking that these "mipmap" folders needed to be changed to "drawable" folders (in the place of "mipmap"). So if anyone did that, backtrack, and instead, add the `drawable-<qualifier>` folders in *addition* to the "mipmap" ones. And then make sure to recompile the app.

Answer (score 0):

To get the image to show on the screen, put the image in a view:

```
return (
    <View
        style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={require('image!bg-splash')} style={styles.bg} />
    </View>
);
```

And add these styles to the view

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
```

Comment: Hi Greg. I tried your suggestion and I'm still getting a blank screen. I edited my question to reflect your answer so I don't get the same suggestion from others.