# Require a var that contains a var in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, var

I'm working with react native and I'm creating a Class for my Buttons. The button contains a image. Down here i've decelerated my button in my view.

```
var imageUrl = { //this is a var from a JSON object there could be more than 20 different images 
          normal: "../assets/images/emoticons/1.png",
          selected: "../assets/images/emoticons/1-selected.png"
}

<Button key={index}
        selected={true}
        onPress={onSelect}
        imageUrl={imageUrl} />
```

In the 'Button' Class I've created a _renderImage function that sets the image in the button.

```
_renderImage(imageUrl){
    let image = (selected === true) ? require(imageUrl.normal) : require(imageUrl.selected); //get the right image url

    console.log('../assets/images/emoticons/1.png'); //logs  '../assets/images/emoticons/1.png'
    console.log(typeof('../assets/images/emoticons/1.png')); //logs string
    console.log(image); //logs '../assets/images/emoticons/1.png'
    console.log(typeof(image)); //logs string

    return (
      <Image source={require(image)} />
    );
```

}

This function gives a error. In the screenshot over here you can see the error. 
[image: Error screenshot in iOS simulator]

When i manual set `<Image source= require('../assets/images/emoticons/1.png)} />` It renders the image. So the image exists on this location.

Similar Questions like this one doesn't fix my problem: 
[Trouble requiring image module in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308937/trouble-requiring-image-module-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is currently possible in React Native, as per docs:

> Note that in order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.

From https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html