# Image from custom.xcassets in React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native

If we want to use an image in React-Native js from Images.xcassets, we simply provide the image name as URI - for eg.

```
<Image style = {styles.someStyle} source = {{uri:'addImage.png'}}>
```

But what if we have a custom created .xcassets ? How can that imageset be accessed from the RN js ?

Answer (score 0):

It's considered as legacy code, but can be imported like:

`<Image source={require('image!custom')} />`

Comment: Downvote for what? This is part of the official RN documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html

Comment: it's not working for me. Where did you find working example?